# VBA Nested Iferror in If function while looping

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, excel-formula

I've only started using VBa and I keep getting an Expected: end of statement error.
I'm not sure what the issue is. I need the vba to loop an if statement with a vlookup and an iferror. I can't set the range because the list will be dynamic.
The more I try to fix the code myself the more messy it gets. I've scoured the internet for help.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

The formula is running on the MasterData tab and pulling from the DataDrop tab.

```
Sub COAB()

    Dim i As Range
    Set i = Sheets("MasterData").Range("D2")
    Dim i2 As Range
    Dim i3 As Range
    Set i2 = Sheets("MasterData").Range("W2")
    Set i3 = Sheets("MasterData").Range("X2")
    Dim MasterData As Worksheet
    Dim DataDrop As Worksheet
    Set MasterData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterData")
    Set DataDrop = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataDrop")

    Do Until IsEmpty(i)
        i2 = "=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(" & MasterData.Range("D2").Address(0, 0) & "," 
    & DataDrop.Range("A:C") & ",3,FALSE)" <> "NULL" & ", & ""Charged Off"" & "," 
    & "Active "),"& Active")"
        i3 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-20],'DataDrop'!A:C,2,FALSE),0)"


    Set i = i.Offset(1)
    Set i2 = i2.Offset(1, 0)
    Set i3 = i3.Offset(1, 0)


   Loop

End Sub
```

The formula in one column should be `=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(D2,DataDrop!A:C,3,FALSE)<>"NULL","Charged Off","Active ")," Active")`

And the other column should be `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2,DataDrop!A:C,2,FALSE),0)`

Comment: This: `... & ",3,FALSE)" <> "NULL" & ...` looks wrong to me. You may want to go over all quotes to make sure they're in the right place and the right quantity

Comment: I had less quotes before and it was still giving me the same error. I thought my count was correct.

Comment: `MasterData.Range("D2").Address(0, 0)` is equivalent to `D2`, you might as well simplify that portion.

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53786825/edit) to provide the expected formula this code should produce?

Comment: This can also be made more efficient. No need to loop cell by cell, you can write the formulas all in one go.

Comment: How can I loop it in one go? Would that elimate the error? Also when I tried D2 all of the cells looped were locked to that one cell and didn't iterate and update as it went down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a loop, just get the last row based on Column D, and write the formulas to the entire range in question in one go. Also, quotation marks within formulas need to be doubled up.

```
Sub COAB()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterData")
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

        .Range(.Range("W2"), .Range("W" & lastRow)).Formula = _
            "=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(D2,DataDrop!A:C,3,FALSE)<>""NULL"",""Charged Off"",""Active ""),"" Active"")"
        .Range(.Range("X2"), .Range("X" & lastRow)).Formula = _
            "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2,DataDrop!A:C,2,FALSE),0)"
    End With

End Sub
```